# Fields not detecting layers when using topology plugin?

Tags: qgis

When I use the topology checker plugin in QGIS, some fields do not detect the layers to establish rules and check the topology, a specific case is, the “must contain” function does not detect LADMCOL layers or QGIS manual layers (created layers). in the next box, in order to establish a rule.